# Array length decision in main method

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

In Java, if array length is decided at *compile time* how is the argument length of `args` in

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

decided at *run time*?

Comment: "Array length is decided at compile time" where did you get that from?

Comment: I think what he means is that it should be of fixed length.

Comment: Your question contains too less information for a good quality question. Add sources from where you got that. Elaborate, give some examples to make your point clear. At least use the formatting tools of the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

The String[] args is the argument that the main method accepts.  It could be of any length.  You just need to define the length of an Array when you are declaring it.  And even then it need not be a literal number.  It just needs to be fixed length.

`String[] s = new String[variable]`

The variable `variable` needs to be an integer and can have any value.

Answer (score 1):

Array length isn't determined at compile-time, it's determined at runtime. Consider:

```
String[] makeMeAStringArray(int size) {
    return new String[size];
}
```

`main`'s arguments array is just created with similar code within the `java` tool.

Example ([live copy](https://ideone.com/4JmS0v)):

```
class Example
{
    static String[] makeMeAStringArray(int size) {
        return new String[size];
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
        String[] a = makeMeAStringArray(n);
        System.out.println("a.length = " + a.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array, it's of fixed length. However, it doesn't have to be a compile-time-constant length. This is valid, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int[] arr = new int[i]; 
}
```

When passing an array to a method:

```
public void foo(int[] arr) { //...
```

you don't specify a size. It just needs to be an array. The length is not enforced by the method signature.

So a combination of these two things means there's nothing special about how the main method is declared.

Answer (score 0):

An array name is essentially an array address. You can declare an array   `String[] args`, but it wont be initialised until you point it to an address or type `String[] args = new String[N]`. 
Now, when an array is in the parameter, it is not initialised, as it doesn't point to anything. But, when you pass an array as an argument to the function, such as `main(arguments)`, String[] args gets the address of arguments array during runtime, and then the main function runs.

When you run a program and give in some input, Java takes the input as a String array, where each argument is seperated by a space in the input, and then feed it to the main function in the Java program. So, the string array args[] isn't initialised in the beginning, but is 'given' the address of the string array of arguments, which would have been taken at run time as input.

Hope this helps!